# How to set memory limit for thread or process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, cross-platform

I'm writing program in Python which would be able to run untrusted python code in some kind of sandbox. So, I need a way to limit the amount of memory that untrusted code can allocate. At now I can limit the maximum length of range(), list, dictionary and the others by overriding default python data structures in my sandboxed environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably just about need to do this at the OS level, not inside of Python (e.g., in Windows you might want to use a job object).

Comment: Would help to specify which OS you need this to work on.

Comment: My OS is Windows but I'm planning to do everything in cross platform way.

Comment: You really can't do this without *some* OS-specific code, as existing OSes (Windows, Mac, Linux, etc) just vary too much.  You can take a cue from `subprocess`, though: `import sys` and then use code like `mswindows = (sys.platform == "win32")`, and define functions inside `if mswindows: ... else: ...`.

Answer (score 7):

Under Unix, you could use [resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, ...)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.RLIMIT_AS) to restrict
"the maximum area (in bytes) of address space which may be taken by the process."

```
import sys
import resource
soft, hard = 10**7, 10**7
# soft, hard = 10**8, 10**8   # uncommenting this allows program to finish
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS,(soft, hard))
memory_hog = {}
try:
    for x in range(10000):
        print(x)
        memory_hog[str(x)]='The sky is so blue'
except MemoryError as err:
    sys.exit('memory exceeded')
    # memory exceeded
```

Comment: Fine! But what about all these Windows machines?

Comment: I don't know how it is done under Windows. Hopefully someone else can supply that part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how it is done under Windows. Hopefully someone else can
>   supply that part of the solution.

Here's some example code to set the limit on Windows using `ctypes`...

```
import ctypes

PROCESS_SET_QUOTA = 0x100
PROCESS_TERMINATE = 0x1
JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation = 9
JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY = 0x100


class IO_COUNTERS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('ReadOperationCount', ctypes.c_uint64),
                ('WriteOperationCount', ctypes.c_uint64),
                ('OtherOperationCount', ctypes.c_uint64),
                ('ReadTransferCount', ctypes.c_uint64),
                ('WriteTransferCount', ctypes.c_uint64),
                ('OtherTransferCount', ctypes.c_uint64)]


class JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('PerProcessUserTimeLimit', ctypes.c_int64),
                ('PerJobUserTimeLimit', ctypes.c_int64),
                ('LimitFlags', ctypes.c_uint32),
                ('MinimumWorkingSetSize', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('MaximumWorkingSetSize', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('ActiveProcessLimit', ctypes.c_uint32),
                ('Affinity', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('PriorityClass', ctypes.c_uint32),
                ('SchedulingClass', ctypes.c_uint32)]


class JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('BasicLimitInformation', JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION),
                ('IoInfo', IO_COUNTERS),
                ('ProcessMemoryLimit', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('JobMemoryLimit', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('PeakProcessMemoryUsed', ctypes.c_void_p),
                ('PeakJobMemoryUsed', ctypes.c_void_p)]


# Set memory limit for process with specfied 'pid', to specified 'size' in bytes
def set_limit(pid, size):

    job_info = JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION()
    out_size = ctypes.c_uint32()

    job = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateJobObjectA(None, None)
    assert job != 0

    success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.QueryInformationJobObject(job,
                                                               JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation,
                                                               ctypes.POINTER(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION)(job_info),
                                                               ctypes.sizeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION),
                                                               ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)(out_size))
    assert success

    job_info.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags |= JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_PROCESS_MEMORY
    job_info.ProcessMemoryLimit = size
    success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetInformationJobObject(job,
                                                             JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation,
                                                             ctypes.POINTER(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION)(job_info),
                                                             ctypes.sizeof(JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION))
    assert success

    process = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_SET_QUOTA | PROCESS_TERMINATE,
                                                 False, pid)
    assert process != 0

    success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.AssignProcessToJobObject(job, process)
    assert success


    success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(job)
    assert success

    success = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(process)
    assert success


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import os

    five_mb = 5 * 1024 * 1024

    def can_we_allocate_five_mb():
        try:
            s = 'x' * five_mb
            return True
        except MemoryError:
            return False

    print can_we_allocate_five_mb()
    set_limit(os.getpid(), five_mb)
    print can_we_allocate_five_mb()
```

...although there's probably no need to create a separate job objects for each process - you should be able to associate all restricted processes with a single job.

Comment: In Python 3 you need to use CreateJobObjectW instead of CreateJobObjectA else only the first character of the job name is seen by Windows.