# How to set memory limit for python program cross-platform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I'm developing a program that depending on input, can end up being extremely memory intensive. I want to give users the option of limiting RAM usage, as well as set a limit when memory threshold is passed so program can exit gracefully with an error message.

I found a previous (old) question that suggested a way of doing this in Unix and python 2: [How to set memory limit for thread or process in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779497/how-to-set-memory-limit-for-thread-or-process-in-python)

But I haven't found an easy clean way to set this limit for cross-platform, was wondering if anyone came across a cleaner way since then.

Comment: There is an answer for Windows in the link. Do `if os.platform == 'nt': ...; else: ...`. If you want to break down the abstraction, there is no clean way to deal with the fallout.

Comment: Try Google. It works wonders.

Comment: The answer is 7 years old :) I was just asking if maybe something was added since then, but thank you anyways.